# Which MacBook Pro configuration is best suitable for Iphone/Ipad App development?

Tags: macbook-pro, development, macos

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are good specs for a MacBook to develop on iOS with?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/3295/what-are-good-specs-for-a-macbook-to-develop-on-ios-with)

I'm planning to buy a MacBook Pro and get into devlopment. But I'd like which is the best configuration I should go for?

Is it necessary to have a dedicated graphics card? Because I was looking at cheaper options like the 13' ones which only have integrated graphics memory.

Comment: Hardware shopping questions are off-topic. Join us on [meta] to discuss what makes a good "requirements" question for the site that you could then learn and take with you when you shop.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're planning on working with an external monitor I'd always go at least with 15" Pro or the 13" Air. Both are fine machines for coding iPhone apps. Working in Xcode on an 13" Pro (1280x800) is doable, but rather unpleasant.

If it'll be your only machine I would recommend the 15" MBP, as you might need Photoshop (or similar) for UI design. At that point you would notice the weaker CPU and graphics in the Air or 13" MBP.